# A sequence of $n$ boolean variables each separated by logical disjunction such that the sequence is true.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Let $p_{1},...,p_{n}$ denote a sequence of boolean variables, for $n\geq2$.

How many distinct assignments are possible for $p_{1},...,p_{n}$ such that the Boolean expression $(p_{1}\lor p_{2}\lor ... \lor p_{n})$ is true?

I'm unsure of how to apply the boolean truth table so I can solve the problem. Do you look at the value of the entire boolean expression as building up from the right?

Comment: How many distinct assignments are possible for $p_1,\dots,p_n$? How many distinct assignments are there such that the disjunction $(p_1\lor\dots\lor p_n)$ is **false**?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, I can first find out how many total distinct assignments there are and subtract 1 because there's only one way for the sequence to be false (when all the variables are false)? @bof

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting your (Tyler's) comment,

> If I understand you correctly, I can first find out how many total distinct assignments there are and subtract 1 because there's only one way for the sequence to be false (when all the variables are false)?

For the expression to be false you need all of the $p_i$s to be false. And hence your proposition stands true. Now as each of $p_i$ can either be true or false (i.e, two choice for each), there are a total of $2^n -1$ possible arrangements.